# Detecting orientation changes in a LED TV/monitor automatically

Tags: display, tv, orientation

I am looking for solutions to use a 42" LED TV as a computer monitor for my digital x-ray application.

I want to have a TV monitor that can sense when it is being spun from portrait to landscape orientations and automatically align the image accordingly. Is there such technology available? Or can it be readily manufactured?

I want to be able to use the TV as a standard computer monitor (landscape) and then to simply spin the TV 90 degrees on edge to view full length x-rays in portrait mode, using an appropriate wall mount. Something like an iPad, I suppose?

Otherwise, is there a sotware application that allows you to switch the orientation with a single click?

Answer (score 1):

TV monitors donot come with accelerometer , as flipping them frequently is not what they are made for . 
You could play around with arduino kits to build one for your tv like this [blog](http://brohogan.blogspot.com/search/label/Accelerometer%20and%20Compass).
Or you could get yourself software like [Pivot](http://www.portrait.com/enu/pivot/overview.html)
Although the easiet way would be to enable your windows hotkeys and then use `ctrl`+`alt`+`arrow keys` to rotate your screen.

Comment: Or have a webcam pointing at the TV and some code to determine the orientation of the TV.  With an arduiono solution, you could just have a circuit that closes when the TV is in portrait, build into the wall mount.  No fancy accelerometers required.

Comment: @Paul : tilting your head might work too ;)